# Getting rid of extra space in a scrolled ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I use a owner drawn ListBox with a big ItemHeight, what works fine so far.
My problem is that there is some blank space at the end of the list, when not all items can be displayed.

Is there any way i can get rid of this space?

I tried setting the IntegralHeight property to true, but this will shrink the ListBox leaving me with the same amount of free control space.

This is what it looks like:

[image: ListBox]

Comment: IIRC that's how a listbox control works (the native control in Windows). If you want to be able to display partial items then you'd need to use a listview.

Comment: I hoped for something i could do about it, now i think i will leave it with a adjusted background color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted in your question, setting IntegralHeight to True will solve the problem-- somewhat.  It will shrink or grow to the next logical size based on the ItemHeight.  So if the ListBox shrinks, try resizing the height to the next size.

Based on your image, it looks like you need to just make it "slightly" larger.  If you don't have the space to make it one unit larger, then you are out of luck with the ListBox.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works as long as the window is not resized. But when it is the gap shows up again. I guess this can't be fixed while using the ListBox control.